# Using multiple programs in OpenCL

Tags: opencl

I am writing a piece of code that utilizes the GPU using OpenCL. I succeeded in making a kernel that runs Vector addition (in a function called `VecAdd`), so I know it is working. Suppose I want to make a second kernel for Vector subtraction `VecSub`. How should I go about that? Or more specifically: can I use the same context for both the `VecAdd` and `VecSub` function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi @debruss welcome to StackOverflow!

Yes, you certainly can run multiple `Kernels` in the same `Context`.
You can define the `Kernels` in the same or multiple `Programs`. You could even run them simultaneously in two different `Command Queues` or a single `Command Queue` configured for `out of order` execution.

There is an example (in `rust`) of defining and running two `Kernels` in a `Program` here: [opencl2_kernel_test.rs](https://github.com/kenba/opencl3/blob/main/tests/opencl2_kernel_test.rs).

Comment: Do you happen to have documentation for this? I got it working, but I am curious where you can find it in the documentation. because I could not find it.

Comment: @debruss [5.8. Program Objects](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/specs/3.0-unified/html/OpenCL_API.html#_program_objects) states; "An OpenCL program consists of a set of kernels". The API is less clear about having multiple program objects, but section 5.8 implies that a Context may have multiple Programs. However, I completely agree with you that the OpenCL documentation is not very clear!